# iOS StoreKit best practice

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

According to the Apple documentation, best practice dictates that `SKPaymentQueue` observer should be added in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and removed in `applicationWillTerminate`. I note however that `applicationWillTerminate` is not guaranteed to be called and that `applicationDidEnterBackground` may be call in its stead. Is this safe?

Comment: To be clear, I am not suggesting that the removal of the observer should be in applicationDIdEnterBackground, i was just seeking clarification on  what seems a hole in the best practice guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`applicationDidEnterBackground` is certainly not an alternative to `applicationWillTerminate`. The former indicates that your app has entered the background and will be suspended.  When your app is about to return to the foreground `applicationWillEnterForeground` will be called.

If `applicationWillTerminate` is called then your app is going to terminate.  When it is relaunched, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be called.

It is true that `applicationWillTerminate` will not always be called, but iOS cannot deliver a payment transaction to a terminated app anyway, so it doesn't matter that the transaction observer may not always be removed.